# LaTeX enumerate levels separated by dots

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, enumerate, punctuation

I have two levels of enumerate lists in LaTeX with labels like

(ii.a)

where the levels are separated by dot. I would like to have references in the same format. However, they are printed as

iia

It is no problem to put the brackets around, but I would like to have also the dot in between. I tried several approaches I Googled, but nothing worked well with the references.

Comment: Could you provide actual peace of the code (text) in this case?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides separate `label` and `ref` keys for you to specify your list representation and cross-referencing with (if you wish them to be different, for some reason):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

See Items~\ref{enum:level2} and~\ref{enum:level1}.

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\roman*)}]
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \begin{enumerate}[label={(\roman{enumi}.\alph*)}]
    \item First nested item
    \item Second nested item \label{enum:level2}
    \item Third nested item
    \item Last nested item
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Third item \label{enum:level1}
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```